# mexopencv needs to re-compile every I restart Matlab

Tags: matlab, opencv, mex

I've recently installed mexopencv for MATLAB on my Windows 7 machine. I'm using MATLAB 2015a 32-bit (on a 64-bit machine). I followed the recommended installation steps (from a number of sources - I had compiler issues to start with) and eventually got it working. The final step in the process is running the following command in MATLAB:

```
mexopencv.make
```

This is fine and I've been using it happily ever since. However, whenever I restart MATLAB and run my code which uses mexopencv functions, I get the following:

```
Error using cv.undistort
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\mexopencv-master\+cv\undistort.mexw32':
C:\mexopencv-master\+cv\undistort.mexw32 is not a valid Win32
application.
```

After some investigation it seems the only way I can get around this is to run the following every time I restart MATLAB:

```
mexopencv.make('clean',true)
mexopencv.make
```

So this is essentially re-compiling the mex files every time I start MATLAB. This takes a good couple of minutes and is a real pain!

Is there some way to get around having to do this each time?

Comment: I've never used mexopencv, but it looks like something is recompiling your binaries in 64-bit.  Can you watch the files in windows explorer to see when they get modified when you exit MATLAB?  By the way, why don't you install 64-bit MATLAB since you are on a 64-bit machine?  Everything is simpler and faster that way.\

Comment: @chappja - Thanks for the suggestion. I exited MATLAB while observing the files in the 'C:\mexopencv-master\+cv\' folder (including the .mex32 files), but nothing was modified. Also nothing was modified on opening MATLAB again.

Comment: @chappja - Regarding using 64-bit MATLAB: I used this initially, but when I started trying to get the mex running that I encountered problems with the Windows 7 64-bit compilers (see the issue discussed in part [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95039-why-does-the-sdk-7-1-installation-fail-with-an-installation-failed-message-on-my-windows-system).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem (needed to rebuild mexopencv every time). Some people said they solved this problem by setting system PATH but not in my case. Mine was solved by copying all opencv dlls to the same directory those compiled mex files are.